# How do I bind class to my return javascript text?

Tags: javascript, vuejs2

I got this function, how can I add a class to this return text? I want it to appear in green text and bigger font size.

```
else if (this.currentWeight == this.goalWeight) {
            return "Congratulations, you have reached your goal weight"
          }
```

Full code:

```
.col-lg-12
     p {{ progressVariant }}
```

````
progressVariant() {
      switch(this.goalType) {
        case "balance":
          if(this.currentWeight == this.goalWeight) {
            return 'You are maintaining your weight'
          }
        case "gain":
          if(this.currentWeight > this.startWeight && this.goalWeight > this.startWeight) {
            return "You are closer to your goal, you've gained " + Math.abs(this.startWeight - this.currentWeight) + "kg"
          }
        case "loss":
          if(this.currentWeight < this.startWeight && this.goalWeight < this.startWeight) {
            return "You are closer to your goal, you have lost " + Math.abs(this.startWeight - this.currentWeight) + "kg"
          } else if (this.currentWeight > this.startWeight && this.goalWeight < this.startWeight) {
            return "You're getting away from your target weight, you have gained " + Math.abs(this.currentWeight - this.startWeight) + "kg"
          } else if (this.currentWeight == this.goalWeight) {
            return "Congratulations, you have reached your goal weight"
          }
        
        default:
          return '';
          break;
      }

    },
    ```
````

Comment: It looks like your approach is not fully "vue-like", that message should be conditionally rendered inside your Vue template with an attribute like `v-if="currentWeight == goalWeight"`. In general you do not manipulate the DOM but only your app state, and your template takes care of generating the HTML based on that state.

Comment: No, because this is a long switch statement, this is just a small part of code i need colourized.

Comment: Doesn't matter, and "long switch statement" sounds bad on its own; if you want help with this, please put all relevant code in the question.

Comment: Ok, I've uploaded entire code.

Comment: @ChrisG is right. It's not the "Vue" way. What seems @ChrisG is recommending is to handle all the conditional CSS inside `<template>` tag, just add some `v-if`s to some tags or utilize Vue's class or style bindings. I recommend instead of switch statement, you can use javascripts' Map or object to map your goal types.

Comment: Looking at the entire code, it's not nearly as removed from Vue best practices as I suspected; it's still a bad idea to insert HTML into that string to turn it green though. Here's a [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/mutable-dream-pf97s?file=/src/components/HelloWorld.vue) I made that kind of goes into the direction of the other extreme; I put most of the switch logic into the template. I guess the optimal solution is somewhere in between.